# Is it possible to retrieve the full viewport height on iOS Safari via JS?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, viewport

I would like to retrieve the full height of the viewport on iOS Safari via JavaScript. `window.innerHeight` is unreliable because it changes as the UI contracts. On my iPhone 12, the following is reported:

- When the page loads, `window.innerHeight` is 664px.
- As I scroll, `window.innerHeight` is increased (eg. 707px).
- Once the UI has fully contracted, `window.innerHeight` is consistently 745px.

In CSS, `100vh` gives me the full height of the viewport when the page loads. Thus I can insert an element to manually measure it:

```js
let d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.position = 'absolute';
d.style.width = '1px';
d.style.height = '100vh';
document.body.prepend(d);
dh = d.clientHeight; // 745px
```

Is it possible to get the value of `100vh` in pixels without inserting an element? There are [new CSS units](https://dev.to/frehner/css-vh-dvh-lvh-svh-and-vw-units-27k4) that accomodate for the changes to the viewport but I'm not sure if there are equivalents in JS.

Thanks for your time and apologies if this is a duplicate question, I could not find it asked before.

Comment: What do you define as 'the full height of the viewport' - obviously it does change on IOS.

Comment: @AHaworth it would the height of the visible part of the webpage. On iOS Safari the bottom ~60 pixels are covered by the address bar, until you scroll down. I'm wondering if there's a property of window (or something else) that would return 745px before scrolling.

Comment: So you want it to return not the visible part of the current set up, but what the visible part will be when the user scrolls? Is that right?

Comment: @AHaworth yes that's an accurate way to describe it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a property of `window` that corresponds to the new `dvh` (Display Viewport Height) CSS unit.

From a practical standpoint, I wanted to set my (dynamically-created) `<canvas>` to `100dvh` via JS when the page loads. This ensures that when the user scrolls on iOS Safari and the browser chrome is hidden, the canvas is already the full height of the window. Before scrolling, `window.innerHeight` only gives the equivalent of `100vh`, not `100dvh`.

My solution was simply to insert the `<canvas>` in the html and set the height to `100dvh` with CSS, then read the dimensions of the element (`el.clientHeight`) back.

Comment: You save me with this dvh property. Thanks @SalutBarbu!

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to get what you are wanting to achieve would be to still use `window.innerHeight` but use a function and a `setInterval` to constantly retrieve the value.  Maybe something like this would work for you:

here's a jsfliddle that you can play around with the viewport screen size and see it change. https://jsfiddle.net/59vyemjt/

```js
var heightjs = function(){
let x = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= x;
}

setInterval(heightjs, 50);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```